# How can i set my site tile(<title> equal to blog.title?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

ok, so i am making a tiny blog site for fun, and i am wondering how i can set the title of a page = blog.title(using nodejs and express)
this is what i have tried, and it did not work ;(.

```
app.get('/blogs/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    Blog.findById(id)
      .then(result => {
        res.render('details', { blog: result, title: `Announcement details ${blog.title} ` });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
});
```

does anyone have any methods that might work?

Comment: You need to set it in `<title>` tag in your template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this piece of code

```
app.get('/blogs/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    Blog.findById(id)
      .then(result => {
        res.render('details', { blog: result, title: `Announcement details ${result.title} ` });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
});
```

***you were using blog.title instead of result.title***